# What is Swift enum byte representation?

Tags: swift, enums, nsdata

I have the following enum:

```
enum Enum: UInt8 
{
  case A = 0x00
  case B = 0x01
  case C = 0x10
}
```

I use the following code to convert it to `NSData`:

```
var value = Enum.C
let data = NSData(bytes: &value, length: 1)
```

Naturally, I expect `data` to contain **`0x10`**, however, it contains **`0x02`**.

For `Enum.A` it contains `0x00` and for `Enum.B` it contains `0x01`.

To me, it looks like it stores an index of the value instead of its actual raw data. Could someone explain this behavior?

P.S. If I use `rawValue` it works perfectly. However, I want to understand the reason behind, since because of it I cannot create a generic function to convert values to NSData.

Comment: In this case the size of the value in bytes is exactly **1** (I used `sizeof` instead of `1`). So it means that the only thing saved is an order number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swift ABI is still work in progress (expected to be fixed with Swift 4). The way enums are represented in memory [is described here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI/TypeLayout.rst#fragile-enum-layout).

Your case is a ["c-like enum"](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI.rst#c-like-enums) because is has...

- two or more cases
- no associated values

Quoting the ABI document:

> the enum is laid out as an integer tag with the minimal number of bits to contain all of the cases. [...] The cases are assigned tag values in declaration order.

The crucial information here is the "minimal number of bits". This means that (for your case) instances should fit into two bits (as you have three cases). The rawValue `0x10` would need five bits—which would be in conflict with the ABI.

The compiler probably uses static tables to convert between instances of `Enum` and their `rawValue` (and back).

Here's an example that highlights this characteristic of the ABI:

```
enum Enum: UInt32
{
    case A = 0
    case B = 0xffffffff    // value that does not fit into one byte
}

assert(sizeof(Enum.self) == 1)
```

Comment: This explains it, thanks. Looks like I will need to use specific `RawValueRepresentable` overload to convert enums to NSData.

Comment: @Werolik It sounds like a good idea not to rely on ABI specifics to build this kind of generic conversion functions for now.

Answer (score 1):

Each enum case is given a standard order value. Which is what you are getting when you don't use `.rawValue`.

For example, if you change your enum to:

```
enum Enum: UInt8 
{
  case A = 0x00
  case B = 0x01
  case B2 = 0x0A
  case C = 0x10
}
```

Then, when executing

```
var value = Enum.C
let data = NSData(bytes: &value, length: 1)
```

`data` will be `3`, because `A = 0`, `B = 1`, `B2 = 2`, `C = 3`

Comment: Can you refer to some piece of documentation for this?