# How does this code to generate enum work in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums

I recently came across this piece of code to generate enums. I can't really make sense of this.

```
enum Alphabet: String {
  case A
  case B
  case C
}

var i = 1

let alphabet = withUnsafePointer(to: &i) { (pt) -> Alphabet in
  UnsafeRawPointer(pt).load(as: Alphabet.self)
}
print(alphabet) // B
```

Result:

```
i = 0 -> alphabet = A
i = 1 -> alphabet = B
i = 2 -> alphabet = C
```

How do you explain this?

I've read somewhere that swift provides `hashValue` method for enum values which returns the value's index inside the enum. Though I'm not sure if this is documented.

Comment: This is very fragile. It relies on a certain memory representation of enums. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305976/what-is-swift-enum-byte-representation and https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI/TypeLayout.rst#fragile-enum-layout.

Comment: I just guess that under the hood an enum in Swift is somewhat logically implemented or represented as an array of the enum's instances, where each instance is maybe represented as a pair of enum's case name and its raw vale. And I also guess that it appears that the memory layout of integer types (Int, UInt, UInt8 ...) is similar to or compatible with that of enums in Swift, therefore it can be loaded and used to index into the underlying array to grab/return the corresponding enum's instance.